# Cassandra columns order by UTF8 encoded string

Tags: php, cassandra

I'm not sure if this is specific question for `Cassandra` or this can also belong to `PHP` so I'm sorry for tagging `PHP`.

So basically i'm ordering some long row columns by their column names, which goes like this:

```
2012-01-01_aa_99999  |  2012-01-01_aaa  |  2012-01-12_aaaaa
```

So this is working the way i want it to work, but i don't understand how does it actually order those string.

What is not clear to me is that first string `2012-01-01_aa_99999` seems to be way bigger then the rest two, and i'm concerned that at some point it might ignore first part of the string which is a **date** and put some string where they shouldn't belong.

In my case those string consist of quite a few parts so i'm really concerned about this, so basically i need some explanation how does this ordering happens internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i don't understand how does it actually order those string.

The strings you provided appear to be [lexicographically ordered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Comment: Now it makes a lot of sense, thou i wonder how would i need to create timestamps in lexicographical format. Well anyways thank you for your answer it showed me that my current approach could create quite a few problems.

Comment: Timestamps could be numerically sorted. A common format is YYYYMMDD.

Comment: You can also use unix epoch for timestamps if you want more precision.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question as I want to construct a composite primary key index with well-understood sorting abilities. It turns out Cassandra appears to compare UTF-8 strings using a [byte-by-byte binary comparison](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/marshal/UTF8Type.java)... this is indeed a completely broken sort function from a logical perspective. If you had mixed ASCII and Kanji characters in your string, for example, your sort order would be effectively random. However, as long as this sort order is known, one can design your usage patterns around it.

This could be easily fixed, of course, and it would be nearly a single-line change of code to patch in a "real" sort function. This would require a bit extra CPU time, of course.